# How in Go lang function returning multiple value can be passed to other function with a variadic parameter

Tags: go

I am new to go programming,

Assume this code, where in function `fmt.Printf()` passing two different values

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
   var a int = 150
   var b int = 130
   var ret1, ret2 int
   ret1, ret2 = max(a, b)
   fmt.Printf( "Max val: %d Min val: %d\n", ret1, ret2 )
}

func max(num1, num2 int) (int,int) {
   if (num1 > num2) {
      return num1, num2
   } else {
      return num2, num1
   }
}
```

Instead of passing ret1, ret2 in `fmt.Printf( "Max val: %d Min val: %d\n", ret1, ret2 )` is there any way, I can directly pass `max(a, b)` in `fmt.Printf()` like

```
fmt.Printf( "Max val: %d Min val: %d\n", max(a, b))
```

I had tried it, it is giving error

> multiple-value max() in single-value context

As it seems, returning two different values not a tuple, is my concept for this returning is wrong or I am doing it wrong.

**Is there any method to pass function with multiple return directly to function require variable number of values**

TIA

Comment: See also: [Golang return values of function as input arguments to another](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35274528/golang-return-values-of-function-as-input-arguments-to-another) and [issue 973](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/973).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [specification](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Calls):

> As a special case, if the return values of a function or method g are equal in number and individually assignable to the parameters of another function or method f, then the call f(g(parameters_of_g)) will invoke f after binding the return values of g to the parameters of f in order. The call of f must contain no parameters other than the call of g, and g must have at least one return value. If f has a final ... parameter, it is assigned the return values of g that remain after assignment of regular parameters.

The problem with the call that you want to make is that one of the arguments to `Printf` is not a return value of `max`.  This call does work work:

```
fmt.Println(max(a, b))
```

https://play.golang.org/p/ZZayVkwZJi

Answer (score 1):

You can do something similar with an inline helper function with a variadic parameter.

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
   var a int = 150
   var b int = 130
   func(i ...int){fmt.Printf( "Max val: %d Min val: %d\n", i[0], i[1] )}(max(a,b))
}

func max(num1, num2 int) (int,int) {
   if (num1 > num2) {
      return num1, num2
   } else {
      return num2, num1
   }
}
```

I hope it helps.

Look at https://play.golang.org/p/tB-q8hjNdu to see it in action.